# Unable access to webex desktop app using tcp mode

Tags: linux, haproxy, webex

I'm running haproxy 2.4 and when the haproxy is configured in http mode, i can't access to webex desktop app, says connecting but instead pass to logon page, back to "select webex website".

Switching to tcp mode, everything work correctly.

Also, this problems continues on haproxy 2.5

Config file in HTTP mode:

```
#  1,5
# CPU(s) 11
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 200000
    nbproc           11
    cpu-map           1 0
    cpu-map           2 1
    cpu-map           3 2
    cpu-map           4 3
    cpu-map           5 4
    cpu-map           6 5
    cpu-map           7 6
    cpu-map           8 7
    cpu-map           9 8
    cpu-map           10 9
    cpu-map           11 10
    uid 0
    gid 0
    chroot  /tmp
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stat mode 600 level admin
    stats bind-process 1
    daemon
#   debug
#   quiet

defaults
    log global
    log-format  HASTATS:::%{+Q}o:::client_ip=%ci:::client_port=%cp:::datetime_of_request=[%tr]:::frontend_name_transport=%ft:::backend_name=%b:::server_name=%s:::time_to_receive_full_request=%TR:::Tw=%Tw:::Tc=%Tc:::response_time=%Tr:::active_time_of_request=%Ta:::status_code=%ST:::bytes_read=%B:::captured_request_cookie=%CC:::captured_response_cookie=%CS:::termination_state_with_cookie_status=%tsc:::actconn=%ac:::feconn=%fc:::beconn=%bc:::srv_conn=%sc:::retries=%rc:::srv_queue=%sq:::backend_queue=%bq:::captured_request_headers_default_style=%hr:::captured_response_headers_default_style=%hs:::server_ip=%si:::server_port=%sp:::frontend_name=%f:::http_method=%HM:::http_request_uri_without_query=%HP:::http_request_query_string=%HQ:::http_request_uri=%HU:::bytes_uploaded=%U:::ssl_ciphers=%sslc:::ssl_version=%sslv:::%[capture.res.hdr(0)]
    mode    http
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    maxconn 200000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend ddsds
    bind    :3128 name ddsds
    capture request header Host len 1024
    capture request header Content-Type len 1024
    capture request header User-Agent len 1024
    capture request header Referer len 1024
    capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 1024
    capture response header Content-Type len 1024
    capture cookie Cookie_2 len 100
    http-request set-header mode mode:tcp
    http-request capture hdr(mode)  len 10
    mode http
    option  httplog
#   http-keep-alive: * 1 *
    option http-keep-alive
    timeout http-keep-alive 15000
    option prefer-last-server
    option redispatch
    no option httpclose
    option http-tunnel
    timeout client  15000
    timeout http-request    50000
    timeout queue   50000

    default_backend default_ddsds

backend default_ddsds
    mode http
    balance leastconn
#   http-keep-alive: * 1 *
    option http-keep-alive
    timeout http-keep-alive 15000
    option prefer-last-server
    option redispatch
    no option httpclose
    option http-tunnel
    timeout connect 4000
    timeout server  50000
    timeout http-request    50000
    timeout queue   50000
    retries 3

    server normal_port 192.168.58.12:50877 weight 1 maxconn 10000 check inter 60000 rise 2 fall 3 source 192.168.58.13

# ddsds no result
frontend admin_page
    bind    127.0.0.1:64741
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats uri /stats
```

Config file in TCP mode:

```
#  1,5
# CPU(s) 11
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 200000
    nbproc           11
    cpu-map           1 0
    cpu-map           2 1
    cpu-map           3 2
    cpu-map           4 3
    cpu-map           5 4
    cpu-map           6 5
    cpu-map           7 6
    cpu-map           8 7
    cpu-map           9 8
    cpu-map           10 9
    cpu-map           11 10
    uid 0
    gid 0
    chroot  /tmp
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stat mode 600 level admin
    stats bind-process 1
    daemon
#   debug
#   quiet

defaults
    log global
    log-format  HASTATS:::%{+Q}o:::client_ip=%ci:::client_port=%cp:::datetime_of_request=[%tr]:::frontend_name_transport=%ft:::backend_name=%b:::server_name=%s:::time_to_receive_full_request=%TR:::Tw=%Tw:::Tc=%Tc:::response_time=%Tr:::active_time_of_request=%Ta:::status_code=%ST:::bytes_read=%B:::captured_request_cookie=%CC:::captured_response_cookie=%CS:::termination_state_with_cookie_status=%tsc:::actconn=%ac:::feconn=%fc:::beconn=%bc:::srv_conn=%sc:::retries=%rc:::srv_queue=%sq:::backend_queue=%bq:::captured_request_headers_default_style=%hr:::captured_response_headers_default_style=%hs:::server_ip=%si:::server_port=%sp:::frontend_name=%f:::http_method=%HM:::http_request_uri_without_query=%HP:::http_request_query_string=%HQ:::http_request_uri=%HU:::bytes_uploaded=%U:::ssl_ciphers=%sslc:::ssl_version=%sslv:::%[capture.res.hdr(0)]
    mode    http
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option  redispatch
    maxconn 200000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend ddsds
    bind    :3128 name ddsds
    capture request header Host len 1024
    capture request header Content-Type len 1024
    capture request header User-Agent len 1024
    capture request header Referer len 1024
    capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 1024
    capture response header Content-Type len 1024
    capture cookie Cookie_2 len 100
    http-request set-header mode mode:tcp
    http-request capture hdr(mode)  len 10
    mode tcp
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option http-tunnel
    timeout client  15000
    timeout http-request    50000
    timeout queue   50000

    default_backend default_ddsds

backend default_ddsds
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    option http-tunnel
    timeout connect 4000
    timeout server  50000
    timeout http-request    50000
    timeout queue   50000
    retries 3

    server normal_port 192.168.58.12:50877 weight 1 maxconn 10000 check inter 60000 rise 2 fall 3 source 192.168.58.13

# ddsds no result
frontend admin_page
    bind    127.0.0.1:64741
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats refresh 10s
    stats uri /stats
```

Anyone can help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using option accept-invalid-http-request in frontend.